# Eliminate render-blocking JavaScript and CSS in my site

Tags: javascript, css

hey there I've got many problems with running  [my site.](http://uprightpose.com) I tried to compress manually some large pictures in my site and also compress css and JS code. but still I got a really long list of re-rendering lines...I really don't no how to use ajax to solve the problem can someone please help me with that?
https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fuprightpose.com%2F&tab=desktop

p.s
my site injects php into WP so I also tried some plugins like fastest cash, autoptimize and so on but it didn't make any changes in my site's speed...